# matching more than one substring in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings:

```
mylist = ['room.ax','room-ax1232upper.bin','room-ki9e0lower.bin','window-rm-down.ax','window-rm-up.ax']
```

I want to iterate through this list and check the string on 2 or more places to make sure I execute the correct function.

for example (pseudocode):

```
for item in mylist:
    if item contains 'room' with extension '.ax':
        call_f1()
    elif item contains 'room' and also 'upper' and with extension '.bin':
        call_f2()
    elif item contains 'room' and also 'lower' and with extension '.bin':
        call_f3()
    elif item contains 'window' and also 'down' and with extension '.ax':
        call_f4()
```

If I was checking for a single substring then it's pretty straight forward:

```
for item in mylist:
    if 'room' in item:
        call_f()
```

But I can't figure out how to do this for multiple substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
for item in mylist:
    if 'room' in item and item.endswith('.ax'):
        call_f1()
    elif 'room' in item and 'upper' in item and item.endswith('.bin'):
        call_f2()
    elif 'room' in item and 'lower' in item and item.endswith('.bin'):
        call_f3()
    elif 'window' in item and 'down' in item and item.endswith('.ax'):
        call_f4()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
for item in mylist:
    item = item.split('.')
    if item[0] == 'room' and  item[1] == 'ax':
        print('room.ax if')
    elif all(i in item[0] for i in ['room','upper']) == True and item[1] == 'bin':
        print('roomupper.bin if')
    elif all(i in item[0] for i in ['room','lower']) == True and item[1] == 'bin':
        print('roomlower.ax if')
    elif all(i in item[0] for i in ['window','down']) == True and item[1] == 'ax':
        print('windowdown.ax if')
```

Comment: I posted something very similar. I'll remove mine.